# Pandas use variable for column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

df

    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

How can I access columns via a variable?

I tried this:

```
cols='A','B'
df[cols]
```

...which resulted in this:

```
KeyError: ('A', 'B')
```

Bonus Question:
What if my data frame were like this?:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

df

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   4   7   1   5   7
1   2   5   8   3   3   4
2   3   6   9   5   6   3
```

and I wanted to do this?:

```
cols=['A','B']
cols2=['C','D']
df[cols,'F',cols2]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try subset by `list` of column names:

```
cols=['A','B']
print df[cols]
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

It is same as:

```
print df[['A','B']]
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Bonus answer:

```
cols=['A','B']
cols2=['C','D']

allcols = cols + ['F'] + cols2
print df[allcols]
   A  B  F  C  D
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  4  8  3
2  3  6  3  9  5
```

Comment: Thanks. I can accept the answer in 4 minutes. If you don't mind, I'm posting an extension to the question above but will create a new question if you prefer.

Comment: Hard question what is better. It is up to you.

Comment: Okay, I'll just post it here unless I don't get a response. I think it will be pretty easy, though.

Comment: Use `print(df[cols])` instead of `print df[cols]` if you are getting errors.